# JAVA, how can i erase al the memory (all variables) to restart input procedure?

Tags: java

is there a way to erase all the memory used in JAVA or variables instead of  manually doing "variable=null" ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you give us more details about what you're trying to achieve, we could maybe help you better.

Comment: That is Garbage Collector's job. Why do you want to do it manually? Having GC is one of Java's advantages.

Comment: I guess you want to show us some code to outline what exactly you want to achieve. Most likely you want to rework your "input procedure"; instead of this code putting "input" into existing objects (that you want to manually "clear") ... let the code return completely new objects.

Answer (score 0):

Do you come from cpp background?
You do not have to do it manually in java.Garbage collector does that for you.
So, as soon as an object becomes unreachable (Because it is no longer referenced OR its scope does not exists any longer).
These unreachable objects will be garbage collected next time it GC runs.
If you are facing some other issues (Memory leak) because of strong references You can try `weak references`.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage Collection is process of reclaiming the runtime unused memory automatically. In other words, it is a way to destroy the unused objects.
To do so, we were using free() function in C language and delete() in C++. But, in java it is performed automatically. So, java provides better memory management.

There are many ways:

1. By nulling the reference
2. By assigning a reference to another
3. by annonymous object etc.

here variable =null means there is no point for saying its memmory is no longer used or it referring null.

The gc() method is used to invoke the garbage collector to perform cleanup processing manually. it works based on garbage collection algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You could have the variables defined in a method and use that method to collect and process the variables.  loop back into the method and java will initialize them for the next run through the method.  the prior variables will be released when you leave the method.